# Rails url attribute's value cannot contain symbol '#'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, url, uri

I've tried send request like this.

> localhost:3000/ws/job_histories/index?agent_id=#1000

But on Controller I've received `agent_id=''` or like this one

> localhost:3000/ws/job_histories/index?agent_id=10#00

I've received `agent_id='10'`. I think problem has because Rails understand it like comment.
How can I correctly received my data. Rails doesn't give me any exception.

Answer (score 6):

The hash symbol is the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and your browser will not send it to the webserver ever.

If you want to send it you need to URL encode it (`%23`), you can achieve that with `CGI.escape('#')`.

Answer (score 5):

This is completely normal, hashes belong to the client, they are not sent to the server.

And `#` is what represent a hash so remove it or encode it

Answer (score 4):

Hash fragments aren't sent to servers from the browser, so this would never work, for any server-side framework, not just Rails.

From [Wikipedia, Fragment identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics):

> Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document...

From [URL Fragments and Redirects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/16/url-fragments-and-redirects-anchor-hash-missing.aspx):

> The Fragment component of the URL is the end of the URL from the hash symbol (#) onward. URL Fragments are never sent to the server in the HTTP request...